# Help me convert this line to C#

Tags: c#

Please help me convert this line to C#.

```
objManagementBaseObject.SetPropertyValue("hDefKey", CType("&H" &
Hex(RegistryHive.LocalMachine), Long))
```

Related References in C#:
System.Management

Thank you.

Additional Info:

Code was originally in VB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `RegistryHive.LocalMachine` is just an enum value, in which case passing it through Hex() is just a waste of time:

```
objManagmentBaseObject.SetPropertyValue("hDefKey", (long)RegistryHive.LocalMachine);
```

Comment: Thanks. I realized it after walking away from the code that the VB line is just trying to typecast it to long.

Comment: I suspect the code was originally written in VB without any casting at all, and the ugly Enum -> Hex -> String -> Object -> Long process was added because in certain cases the wrong conversion was happening. That's the more-charitable way you find this kind of code

Answer (score 0):

```
objManagementBaseObject.SetPropertyValue("hDefKey", (long)RegistryHive.LocalMachine);
```

is the C# equivalent to the VB.NET line.

Thanks for the insight!